# gradle constraints for transitive dependencies only

Tags: gradle, dependencies, constraints, transitive-dependency

I want to make sure any transitive dependencies (ie dependency of my dependencies) are using the correct version without pulling in the dependency itself.

For instance my project depends on B (and other dependencies) which depends on C.  I want C to always be v2.

I tried this code

```
constraints {
    implementation('C') {
        version {
            require '2'
        }
        because 'I cant use previous versions'
    }
}
```

I am specifically using *constraints* because that seems to be gradle's recommended way of dealing with transitive properties.

However, my dependency report looks like:

runtimeClasspath

```
+--- B
|    \--- C:2
+--- C:2
```

whereas without the code above, it was just

```
+--- B
     \--- C:1.X
```

Meaning the v2 of the C library also got added to my runtimeClasspath directly.

Is there any gradle code that just ensure that my transitive dependencies are set to a particular version and NOT also add the library version as a direct dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gradle dependency constraints do exactly what you are looking for.

Even if the dependency is listed in the output of `gradlew dependencies`, it's not strictly included in the build.
Notice how dependency `C` is marked with `(c)`, which clearly states it's only a constraint and not a strict requirement:

```
+--- B
|    \--- C:1.X -> 2
\--- C:2 -> 2 (c)

(c) - dependency constraint
```

In fact, it's only listed because at least one other dependency requires it: should you have defined a constraint on a dependency `D` that was not required transitively by any dependency, it wouldn't ever have been shown.

Excerpt from the official Gradle documentation:

> The version definition for `commons-codec:1.11` is only taken into account if `commons-codec` is brought in as transitive dependency, since `commons-codec` is not defined as dependency in the project. **Otherwise, the constraint has no effect.**